# Is there an accepted practice for cross-form control manipulation?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, forms

Let's say I have two forms: **Form1** and **Form2**. Form1 has a textbox, **Textbox1** and **Button1**.

When Button1 is clicked, a new instance of Form2 is created and shown. If Form2 needs to access Textbox1, how should expose it? Should Form2 have a public variable to hold a reference to the textbox? Or, when Form2 closes, should it invoke some public method on Form1 that updates the textbox? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably add a public property to the first form that exposes the textbox's text.

However, much more importantly, *you should name your controls and forms*.
There is (almost) nothing worse than a form with controls `textBox1`, `button1`, `comboBox13`, `checkBox37`.

Comment: The names were as so just to simplify things. Rest assured, I **never** use that naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

If Form2 needs the text box value from Form1 when it loads, I would add the value to Form2's constructor method and pass it in that way.

If Form1 needs to obtain a new value entered in Form2 you can create a delegate with an Event that passes the value back to an assigned event handler in Form1.

Creating a public property may be the fastest solution, but I would try to stay away from circular references between forms if that is the case.

Hope this helps!